# Returning multiple variables with view::share( ) - Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to return multiple variable to my view.

```
$currentUser = Auth::user();
$needToBePassed = "Lorem Ipsum"
View::share ( 'currentUser', $currentUser);
```

This code works fine, however how can if I also want to share `$needToBePassed`, what should I do?

Is rewriting it is a good practice?

```
View::share ( 'currentUser', $currentUser);
View::share ( 'needToBePassed', $needToBePassed);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can pass an array of data,

```
$data = array(
    'currentUser' => $currentUser,
    'needToBePassed' => $needToBePassed,
);
View::share('data', $data);
```

Comment: but then I'll need to call $data['currentUser'], right?

Comment: Yeah. Is that a problem?

Comment: No, other than I need to change my views. I thought there could be a way to return multiple data like `compact`. That way, it would be more tidy code

Comment: You can use `extract($data)` to extract `$currentUser` and other elements.

Comment: That could be a way too. Also, is it bad if I have multiple view::shares?

Comment: No, it isn't. You can do it.

Answer (score 8):

I know the question is already answered, but maybe I can still help a few people by adding this solution. This way you don't have to change all your views.

I was looking for a way to solve this issue without changes all my views.

```
$currentUser = Auth::user();
$needToBePassed = "Lorem Ipsum";

View::share(['currentUser' => $currentUser, 'needToBePassed' => $needToBePassed]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to write mulitple **view:share** command for variable. you can send all of them in a single command.The **view:share**  basically takes array and it does not matter how you will send this array. you can use the inbuilt function compact to make the code smaller.

```
$currentUser = Auth::user();
$needToBePassed = "Lorem Ipsum"
View::share(compact('currentUser','needToBePassed'));
```

***Tested and working in Laravel 7 and 8***

Answer (score 0):

simply compact your variables as parameters like what you do when you return to a view with compacted data/parameters. Just like what Prakhar Gyawali stated, tested and working in laravel 8.

```
View()->share(compact('currentUser','needToBePassed'));
```